# Cloud Functions for Firebase child_added

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying out Cloud Functions for Firebase, creating a function which will add a nickname when a new user is added to the database (not on auth). 
From the [Firebase Documention](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added) I've found that I need to use:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) { 
    //Something
})
```

, but I cannot even get the function to deploy. My code is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var ref = admin.database().ref("/users");

ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
  console.log(snapshot)
})
```

Can someone help me?

#### Update:

After working on it this is now my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref('users');
var childs = [];
var nicknames = [];

exports.newUser = functions.database.ref('users').onWrite(event => {
    const data = event.data.val();
    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, childKey) {
        if (!childs.includes(childKey)) {
            childs.push(childKey);
        };
        for (i in childs) {
            if (childs[i] == null) {
                childs.splice(i, 1);
            };
        };
    });

    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        for (i in childs) {
            var child = data[childs[i]];
            if (!child.hasOwnProperty("nickname")) {
                console.log("Child does not have nickname: " + childs[i]);
                ref.child(childs[i]).update({
                    nickname: "user"+childs[i]
                });
            };
        };
    });
});
```

Based on what Doug Stevenson has replied, I still need to figure out how to only do this if there's actually a new child being added (new user)

Comment: hi, any solution regarding this problem ? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not. The only solution I have found is the one I posted beneath, but it still fires every time something is written to the users only when a child is added straight beneath 'users'

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Here's the code I used:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var childs = [];
var nicknames = [];

exports.newUser = functions.database.ref('users').onWrite(event => {
    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, childKey) {
        if (!childs.includes(childKey)) {
            childs.push(childKey);
        }
    });
});
```

I would like it only to be called when a child is added and not every time something is written to the database (to limit usage)

Comment: I don't think that's going to work out the way you want.  You're definitely going to have problems in the future if you try to register a persistent listener inside a function like that.  If you want to know when a new node is added, you have to check the previous value of the snapshot in the event to see if it's null.  That's how you know a write added new data instead of modifying existing data.

Comment: Would it be enough with:
`if (snapshot.previous.val()) {
    return;
  }`
as suggest on [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#9)

Comment: Yes @GlennHerping, as the comment on the source code explains,   // Only send a notification when a new message has been created. It should work.